# R dplyr divide between two rows after group by

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame like this:

```
x <- data.frame(
    name = rep(letters[1:4], each = 2),
    value = c(2,10,4,20,8,40,20,100)
)
```

I want to group by name, then divide the bottom row by upper row.

result should look like:

```
  name divideValue
1    a           5
2    b           5
3    c           5
4    d           5
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
x %>%
 group_by(name) %>%
 summarise(value = last(value)/first(value))

  name  value
  <fct> <dbl>
1 a         5
2 b         5
3 c         5
4 d         5
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[, .(value =last(value)/first(value)) , name]
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
    group_by(name) %>% 
    summarise(value = value[n()]/value[1])
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
aggregate(value ~ name, x, FUN = function(x) tail(x, 1)/head(x, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
x %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(value = Reduce(`/`, rev(value)))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  name  value
  <fct> <dbl>
1 a         5
2 b         5
3 c         5
4 d         5
```